Get Nest.JS microservice to only process one job from Kafka
Given that I have a Nest.JS job that I would like to run when my kubernetes job triggers a container, how do I limit nest so that it only processes one message from my Kafka topic and then exists gracefully (if the message was handled correctly of course).
